# lost device tokens on server apns

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

We have a table containing apns device tokens on our servers and due to unforeseen circumstances lost all data, including backups. In order to send push notifications we need to send device tokens along with message, since we lost all the tokens, is there any way to get them through apple/ application ? I'm pretty clueless on how to proceed further, any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API that gives you the device tokens for which your app registered to APNS.

Assuming that your app doesn't send the device token to your server every time it is launched, you'll have to release a new version that would send the device token to the server. Then you'll get the device token of every user who installs the updated version and launches the app. You won't recover the tokens of users who don't install the update, but there's nothing you can do about it.

I hope you have better backups next time.